# Javascript: Store a global variable for a single page application

Tags: javascript, window, global-variables, session-storage

A have a react application using a single page. I call index.html and use ajax(axio) and update the page. I do not use any routing.

I have some global variables and will use in the whole scope of the application. The variables are primitive type integer for example. Some of the variables may be updated during the app lifecycle and some remain constant. But I should be able to reach them from all react components/javascripts. They may contain business related constants or example decimal format mask, keeping them private in each component will not be useful.

There is no need/reason to store it on the disk (localStorage).

Question is: what is the best way (performance etc) storing the global variable foo in the app?

```
window.foo = 10 or
window.sessionStorage.foo = 10
```

AFAIK, window.foo is for a single page and sessionStorage allows using within multiple pages within the same origin. What is best in my case when I use a single page? Are there any other drawbacks of **window.foo** usage? Security is not important, the vales stored are not sensitive. Most critical is the performance.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) rather than either of those. From that documentation:

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language.

Definitely don't use global variables. The global namespace is **incredibly** crowded, and adding to it is generally not best practice. If you *did* use a global for this, I'd recommend using just one, and having it refer to an object with properties for the various pieces of information you want to share. Note that they'll be window-specific.

One reason to possibly consider using `sessionStorage` (or perhaps periodically synchronizing your React context to it) is if you want changes in one window to be reflected in another window. Two windows/tabs from the same origin share the same `sessionStorage` and can get an event (`storage`) when the other one changes that storage. So if the global information were an app theme (say, light vs. dark), changing it in one tab could also affect the other tab if you respond to the `storage` event by updating your React context. Note that `sessionStorage` (and `localStorage`) only store *strings*, so the usual thing is to convert to JSON when storing (`JSON.stringify`) and from JSON when loading (`JSON.parse`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, another question we are already using redux, is it possible to mix them? I think context is counterpart of redux and it is not possible to totally switch from redux.

Comment: @benchpresser - Sorry, I haven't used Redux.